# Infer a keyof generic parameter from the function argument

Tags: typescript

```js
function runOnlyGivenActions<T extends object, A extends keyof T>(
  actions: readonly A[]
) {
  // do something with actions
  console.log(actions);
  type T2 = Pick<T, A>;
}

interface Foo {
  hello(): string
  answer(): number;
  dontSelectMe(): void;
}

runOnlyGivenActions<Foo, "hello" | "answer">(["hello", "answer"])
```

The `A` generic parameter acts as a "filter" of the T function members, in order to build a new type for instance (`Pick<T,A>`).

---

In case you wonder, `runOnlyGivenActions` does not have any `T` concrete instance function argument (besides `actions`) because it just needs the "contract" of it. In my case, inside this function, under certains circonstances, I dynamically load (`await import`) a nodejs module and get the concrete class (implementing `T`) from it.

---

**My question is**: is it possible to do something in order to not be forced to pass `"hello" | "answer"` as the second generic entry and infer it from the given array argument?
Ideally, I would like to just type: `runOnlyGivenActions<Foo>(["hello", "answer"])`.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJ3AeTAGwJ4HEYBuApmAILTxgDOAPACqJEAeUJAJlYnAEYBWR0ADSJSjFu04BrItjjBEdAHwAKAIYUEVAFwoiqtghwiA2gF0AlIgDeAKESIA9A8QHEVOAFsiUABYwwAOaIAO4wvojqsJp2iBCacJhEAHSYcAFqGtTmANwxUNgADkQKAEyIALyIAAowEJL0wqSKNgC%20Njb%20rMjA6sUAYnBw1jE%20RJipyuY6VFDI-gExqtTBRMiTOmAgHtyrufYGYFAAymMCUACyROuIBHAwbLltNqhgGDj4xGSZtANwwgBEo3GcH%20iAAPoh-ksqCtkP8VMZAWNUv8AdDYf8LEA)

Comment: You don't need to give it any generic parameters at the call site - this works just fine: `runOnlyGivenActions(foo, ["hello", "answer"])`. Is that what you mean?. `Foo` is also inferred by the fact that you're passing `foo` where `T` is used in your definition.

Comment: My initial example was bad, I cannot pass any instance object as argument :(

Comment: Yes, the example is insufficient, if you can't pass any instance as an argument, then you don't have a `T` - so what are you trying to do?

Comment: I just need to pass an object type and some of its methods names, I have no concrete instance of this type to pass because I just have the "contract" :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *partial type inference* and is not supported yet. The standard workaround is to curry the function instead:

```
function runOnlyGivenActions<T extends object>() {
    return <A extends keyof T>(actions: readonly A[]) => {
        // do something with actions
        console.log(actions);
        type T2 = Pick<T, A>;
    };
}

runOnlyGivenActions<Foo>()(["hello", "answer"]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJ3AeTAGwJ4HEYBuApmAILTxgDOAPACqJEAeUJAJlYnAEYBWR0AHwAKAJSIA3gChEslESghkSGqUYt2nANZFscYIjoiAhhQRUAXPONsEORKQDaAXXEBeQZJlyfAel+ItohUcAC2CgAWMGAA5ogA7jBQEYimsObePrIQ5nCYRAB0mHAxwmmUVKIA3JlZUNgADkSGAEyIbogACjAQWvQANA6CNT4AvjWjUlLRrMjAps0AYnBwXj4RRJjFYlZUUMjRMSNyxtTxRMg7iGAgodwXx7K2YFAAypsCUACyRFcEcDA2BMpqgwBgcPhiGQzNQaMs4CJRMJHAAiDZbOAowYo05Uc7IFGuGpAA)